# ANR while starting new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

Hi I'm displaying screen for 3 seconds and then I'm starting new activity but on Android 5.0 there is a black screen for almost 10 sec and ANR. This is all code from activity which is displaying for 3 seconds:

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService worker =
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Crashlytics.start(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_fragment);
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    };
    worker.schedule(task, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

And logs from logcat:

```
Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord
I/InputDispatcher(  725): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken
It has been 5005.0ms since event, 5003.6ms since wait started.  
Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it     finishes starting up.
I/WindowManager(  725): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken
 Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when     it finishes starting up.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to use `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)` ?

Comment: Why are you displaying a splash screen?

Answer (score 4):

Why go lengthy process while you have an easy one. As @Chen commented above, you can start `MainAcitivity` like this

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();               
    }
}, 3000);
```